# htaccess mod_rewrite problems, what's wrong with my file?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What's wrong with my .htaccess file?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?mode=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Basically I want it to go from example.com/?mode=page&id=1 to example.com/page/1

From what I see,it's supposed to work but it doesn't...

Comment: Isaac, this is a Q of RTFM :-)  You don't include the leading slash in rule patterns in what is called a "directory context".  This includes use in `.htaccess` files.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove leading `/` from your rule
2. Add `RewriteBase /` after `RewriteEngine` line